# .Net Webmaster API is incorrectly encoding URLs (Google.Apis.Webmasters.v3)

Tags: c#, .net, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been struggling to get the new API to work. I am often getting this error when executing a query:

Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 0, position 0.

From investigation I think the .Net code is incorrectly encoding URLs in the request by leaving slashes (/) unencoded. This changes the requests URL path and causes a 404.

If you omit the http:// part from the {site} part of a request it works. e.g. **domain.com** not **http://domain.com/**

There is no work around if your use an https site. Nor can you make any requests that require you to pass a specific URL outside the home page, as it will need to include a slash (/).

Comment: possibly related to https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/510 or https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/534

Comment: @DaImTo #534 is the one. So it's a known bug. Thanks.

Comment: its an open source project so you are welcome to fix it.

Comment: If you have any problems comment on the issue and i will see if i can help.

Comment: Thanks. My version of visual studio is too old to open the project (2010). I might upgrade to 2015 Community. From what I heard that will fix the problem anyhow (.Net 4.5 seems to fix the bug).

Comment: If 4.5 does fix it that helps me track it down. I will see if I can find sometime to deal with it.  Glad you got it working.

Comment: That was some work, just to get 2015 up and running. I can now make api requests with slashes in them, so something was changed between .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5

Comment: The code is slightly different in the client library for .net 4.0 and 4.5.  Due to the differences in framework.   If something was fixed in 4.5 and not in 4.0 then yes there could be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being tracked here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/534

It relates to using .Net 4.0, and can be fixed by upgrading to .Net 4.5

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have done it in Google Geocode API. Not sure if that will help you but hope you get the idea.

```
public static string Sign(string url, string keyString)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

            // converting key to bytes will throw an exception, need to replace '-' and '_' characters first.
            string usablePrivateKey = keyString.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(usablePrivateKey);

            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            byte[] encodedPathAndQueryBytes = encoding.GetBytes(uri.LocalPath + uri.Query);

            // compute the hash
            HMACSHA1 algorithm = new HMACSHA1(privateKeyBytes);
            byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(encodedPathAndQueryBytes);

            // convert the bytes to string and make url-safe by replacing '+' and '/' characters
            string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_");

            // Add the signature to the existing URI.
            return uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + uri.LocalPath + uri.Query + "&signature=" + signature;
        }
```